# Create a repeating task in Jorte

Tags: jorte

How do I create a repeating task in Jorte? I don't want to create a repeating event - just a repeating task.

For example, say I want to create a task "Grade papers" that will happen once a week. It's not an event, it's a task.

Comment: Can't find any way for repeating task... maybe you could send an email to their developer for this [tag:feature-request]!